# move and append certain string to previous index from next index of an array

Tags: php

#gettingstuck

```php
$strings = [
    'To see the DOCX conversion in action, simply "<g id="2">Convert".',
    '</g> Set the output format and click <g id="3">"OK"</g>.'
];

$processedStrings = [
    'To see the DOCX conversion in action, simply "<g id="2">Convert".<\g>',
    ' Set the output format and click <g id="3">"OK"</g>.'
];
```

how do I turn the `$strings` to `$processedStrings`?

this is how it works:

if the next index of `$strings` contains `<\g>` at the start of the string, the `</g>` will be moved and appended to the previous index of `$strings`. Hence you'll notice the next index of `$processedStrings` , the `</g>` at the start of the string is "trimmed"

tried this but got unexpected result

```php
$processedStrings = [];
foreach ($strings as $key => $string) {
    $gClosingTag = '</g>';
    
    if (strpos($string, $gClosingTag) == 0) {
        $addGClosingTagToPrevString = "{$strings[$key - 1]}{$gClosingTag}";
        $processedStrings[] = $addGClosingTagToPrevString;
    } else {
        $processedStrings[] = $string;
    }
}

var_dump($processedStrings);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => To see the DOCX conversion in action, simply "<g id="2">Convert".</g>
    [1] => To see the DOCX conversion in action, simply "<g id="2">Convert".</g>
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, which may be a simpler approach than your code:

A) Iterate through the array $strings

B) For each iteration, pass the iterated array element by reference, using the `&`, such that you can change its value upon iteration, if needed (i.e. as checked in your code, if the iterated string starts with `<g/>` via `strpos()` (but you should rather use the strict equality operator === here and not ==, as coercion to `false` would also enter your loop; as written in the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.strpos.php)), set the value of the iterated string to its value without the first 4 characters (= `</g>`).

C) And in this case, as in your code, add the tag to the end of the previous element.

```
foreach ( $strings as $key => &$string_to_check ) {

  if ( strpos( $string_to_check, '</g>' ) === 0 && $key !== 0) {

    $string_to_check = substr( $string_to_check, 4 );
    $strings[ $key - 1 ] = $strings[ $key - 1 ] . '</g>';

  }

}
```

Comment: A good answer includes an explanation of what was changed and why, so that OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Comment: Aside from that, this a) will produce an "Undefined index" notice for the first element and b) uses JS concatenation syntax instead of PHP.